# MS Access: Search Field to search for an entry in a table with a combobox in it

Tags: vba, ms-access

My issue is that if I want to search for a article in my database, I can do it so for his article Nr., supplier Nr. or its Name. If I want to search for the supplier, which is linked in this table via a combobox to another table, I can't type in the name, only the ID which this supplier has in this other table. How can I change that it searches for the name?

Lieferant= Supplier in this case and Artikel is the table it gets its data, where the articles are saved in and the Row there is called Lieferant, which is linked as a combobox to another table called Lieferanten

```
For Each term In searchTerms
        ' Now so we can search for numbers which were entered with a space or a dash
        completeSearchQuery = completeSearchQuery & _
            "(Bezeichnung LIKE '*" & term & "*' OR " & _
            "removeCharsForPN(Lieferant_PN) LIKE '*" & term & "*' OR " & _
            "removeCharsForPN(Hersteller_PN) LIKE '*" & term & "*' OR " & _
            "Lieferant_PN LIKE '*" & term & "*' OR " & _
            "Hersteller_PN LIKE '*" & term & "*' OR " & _
            "Lieferant LIKE '*" & term & "*') AND "
    Next term
                    
    ' Remove the last AND
    If Len(completeSearchQuery) > 10 Then
        completeSearchQuery = "WHERE " & Left(completeSearchQuery, Len(completeSearchQuery) - 4)
        
        ' Extend the query with another search
        Dim cterm As String
        cterm = removeCharsForPN(SearchString)
        completeSearchQuery = completeSearchQuery & " OR removeCharsForPN(Lieferant_PN) LIKE '*" & cterm & "*' OR " & _
                                                    "removeCharsForPN(Hersteller_PN) LIKE '*" & cterm & "*'"
    
    End If
    

    ' Create the SQL Query
    searchQuery = "SELECT * FROM Artikel " & completeSearchQuery & ";"
```

I tried Lieferant.text to get the text but it doesn't work

Comment: You would have to JOIN Lieferanten and Artikel tables in the SQL statement so the descriptive name field from Lieferanten is available.

Comment: Cheers, solved my problem that I had for days now